# I can't get ProcessCmdKey to work?

Tags: c#, winforms, process, cmd, key

My code:

```
 using System.Windows.Forms

 class Class1
 {
      protected override bool ProcessCmdKey (ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
      {
           if (keyData == Keys.Up)
           {
                Console.WriteLine("You pressed the Up arrow key");
                return true;
           }

           ...//and other code lines for Keys.Down, Keys.Left, Keys.Right

           return true;
      }
 }
```

But all I get the error:

> (namespace).(class).ProcessCmdKey(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message, System.Windows.Forms.Keys): no suitable method found to override.

And if I switch out the

```
 return true;
```

for

```
 return base.ProcessCmdKey (ref msg, keyData);
```

I get the error:

> 'object' does not contain a definition for ProcessCmdKey.

In fact, my ProcessCmdKey text isn't even turning green in color but it stays black when I know it's supposed to be a green color.

Is it something with the .NET Framework version I'm using? If anything, I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 to compile and run my codes.

Or is it something to do with the security level of my class? I'm working with a public-level class

I'm just learning how to register user key inputs as a beginner. I've looked ALL OVER the internet about this topic and this is the same code that's being brought up but I can't get it to work. Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

The method `ProcessCmdKey` is defined in the class `System.Windows.Forms.Control`. So unless you are overriding it in a control (or form) this won't work.

Your class `Class1` does not inherit from a control, therefore you can't overrride the method (because it doesn't exist).

The Error message

> 'object' does not contain a definition for ProcessCmdKey

Pretty much tells you exactly that. `object` is the base class for your `Class1` (implicit) and the class `object` (baseclass of everything) doesn't have that method.

[Form.ProcessCmdKey on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.processcmdkey%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[Control.ProcessCmdKey on MSND](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.processcmdkey%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: How can I make my Class1 inherit from a control so I can override it?  Or do I have to create another separate class?  I've been consulting the MSDN website before I decided to ask this on here since the website isn't really very clear for me because it doesn't list an Example for how to implement ProcessCmdKey.

Comment: In your question, you never mention what you are trying to do with that code. As for `How can I make my Class1 inherit from a control`: Put your code in the `Form1.cs` or if you don't have one, create a new project with a `Windows Forms Application` template

Comment: Ah, I see -- so far I've only worked with console-based cs but I will try out the Form1.cs.  The code I was writing is just to test out how to register user input when a keyboard arrow key is pressed -- I'm just a beginner and slightly new to C# programming and I just wanted to get the basics of registering simple keyboard key presses including arrow keys.

Comment: In that case, you might be looking for `Console.ReadKey`  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readkey%28v=vs.110%29.aspx